# Abrir uma determinada pasta criada por mim no android

Tags: android

Minha aplicação cria uma pasta no android e em uma tela quero ter um botão que quando clicado abra aquela pasta, e só aquela que especifiquei, mas ate agora não achei nada sobre o assunto.

Comment: A resposta abaixo resolve? Sua pergunta não está muito clara, pode explicar o que quer dizer com "abrir" a pasta? É listar os nomes dos arquivos?

Answer (score 2):

O android possui o `Intent` que facilita muito estas ações, que seria uma chamada de telas/actions pré-definidas do android onde você só especifica o que quer e o resto ele cuida para você, acredito que sua intenção se resolveria com apenas este simples código:

```
Uri selectedUri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/suaPasta/");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(selectedUri, "resource/folder");
startActivity(intent);
```